# What's the point in storing objects in memory when you can store them in a databse?

Tags: php

For my PHP based assignment, I believe I have to use objects (Including items like a collection class, collection iterator and so on), as well as a MySQL database.

My question is, why would I need to create items as objects, store them in a database then create them as objects again when pulled out of the database when I can just put and get the items straight into and out of the database and use them for what I need straight away?

Or perhaps better phrased, what would be the benefit, if there is one, of storing objects in PHP memory (Wherever PHP stores things), as well as storing them in a database as opposed to just storing them in a database?

Comment: The in-between memory between your php application and the mysql database offers many advantages, such as if you need to check if an item is in the database you can check if its in the in-between memory, therefore minimizing the queries you need to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing data in memory, as objects, is only a representation of your data from the database -- the two are not the same. 
PHP objects in memory are not persistent at all, your MySQL storage is. Having them "in memory" is just for usage "simplicity".

Comment: You work with the data in memory, and store the data in the database - simply put.

Comment: Exactly. It seams like a very simple concept, but it looks like its explanation is not so trivial :)

Answer (score 1):

Storing and retrieving objects from a database (or other disk-based storage) has considerable overhead vs. storing and retrieving from memory.  Try creating a simple benchmark application and you will notice the difference.

Comment: We are talking here about the concept of caching, which is not the same with storing. Things "stored" only in memory are basically not stored at all.